# How to get global variable declared in Main.cpp to be accessible in a header

Tags: c++, global-variables, c-preprocessor

How would I get a global variable to appear in a header that's included after the variable's declaration?  I have it arranged like this, but within the header, it's not recognized as being defined:

main.cpp:

```
const int COUNT = 10;
void (* FUNCTION[COUNT])();
const char * DESCRIPTION[COUNT];

#include "TestFont.h"
```

testFont.h:

```
#define COUNTER_VAR = __COUNTER__;
DESCRIPTION[COUNTER_VAR] = "description";
FUNCTION[COUNTER_VAR] = func;
#undef COUNTER_VAR
```

In the header, `DESCRIPTION` and `FUNCTION` are seen as undefined, how would I make it so they can be used?

Disclaimer:  It's super ugly isn't it!  This is strictly for a sandbox project in VS, so I can write small single-file tests or scripts in C++ with as little IDE setup ceremony as possible.  The goal is to make it so all I need do is include the header in main.cpp, and main will have the necessary function pointer and description to list it as an option in the console.  No grades please!

Comment: Did you try an `extern` declaration?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - yes, but it didn't seem to change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lines are not legal outside of a function body.

```
DESCRIPTION[COUNTER_VAR] = "description";
FUNCTION[COUNTER_VAR] = func;
```

You may need to wrap that in a helper function.

```
static int init()
{
#define COUNTER_VAR = __COUNTER__;
   DESCRIPTION[COUNTER_VAR] = "description";
   FUNCTION[COUNTER_VAR] = func;
#undef COUNTER_VAR
}
```

and call the function.

```
static int dummy = init();
```

Comment: oh!  I didn't realize.  If assignments are illegal at that scope, may as well replace the `__COUNTER__` hack with a vector pushback too.  Thanks

Comment: @Clairvoire, that would certainly be better.

Comment: @RSahu why do you declare as static?

Comment: @Ghooo, using `static` allows `init` and `dummy` to be defined in more than one source file. It allows different source files to execute independent blocks of code at static initialization time.